# Hanging on lack of DB connection

Tags: java, mysql, jdbc

This code to connect to the database appears to hang for a very long time if our connection to our DB is down or there are no available connections in the pool. I get a CommunicationsException: Communications link failure which doesn't seem to get caught by the exception handling because the application hangs long after that's returned. How do I make this fail faster (dataSource.setLoginTimeout()? maxWait on the TomCat config?) and how do I keep this from hanging? :

```
   try {
      connection = dataSource.getConnection();
    } catch (SQLException e) {
        LOG.error(e.getMessage());
    }
```

Comment: Have you tried any of the suggestions you've provided? It seems as though [`dataSource.setLoginTimeout()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/sql/CommonDataSource.html#setLoginTimeout(int)) would serve your purpose.

Answer (score 0):

The solution was to add a connect timeout parameter on the DB's url in the config.

?connectTimeout=4000